# Example of a Subgroup That Is Not Normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Can you kindly provide an example of a subgroup that is not normal?  I have been told many times that, for coset multiplication to be defined, the subgroup must be normal.  I have seen the proof and examples of quotient group multiplications.  Now, I am trying to find out where the process will break down if the subgroup is not normal.

Suppose that $x \in a_1H = a_2H, y \in b_1H = b_2H$, where $H$ is not normal.
So $x = a_1h_1 = a_2h_2$ for some $h_1, h_2 \in H$, and $y = b_1h_1^* = b_2h_2^*$ for some $h_1, h_2 \in H$. 
$xy = (a_1b_1)(h_1h_1^*) = (a_2b_2)(h_2h_2^*)$.  However, both $h_1h_1^*, h_2h_2^*$ are still elements of $H$. 
So I don't see how $a_1b_1H \neq a_2b_2H$.

Comment: When you multiplied $x$ and $y$ you changed the order of some of the elements. To see a concrete example where it fails, try a subgroup of order $2$ in $S_3$.

Comment: Indeed, in fact if the group is abelian, then every subgroup is normal and everything works. The problem is that not every group is so nice..

Comment: One example in finite structures: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159722/normal-subgroup-question-example/1203102#1203102

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that in your proof, $xy = (a_1h_1)(b_1h_1^*)$. When you write that $xy = (a_1b_1)(h_1h_1^*)$ is *assuming* the group in question is abelian. But this assumption is unwarranted, because when commutativity does **not** hold, we **cannot** assume $xy = (a_1h_1)(b_1h_1^*)=(a_1b_1)(h_1h_1^*)$.

Indeed, if a group is abelian, then every one of its subgroups are normal, as you've shown to be the case, but this doesn't hold in nonabelian groups.

Consider, for example, the group $G = S_3$ and the subgroup $H\lt G$, $H = \{id, (12)\}$. This group is not normal in $S_3$. Consider other non-abelian groups, as well, to find many other counterexamples.

Comment: @ All:  Yes, you guys are right.  In my example, I assumed the abelian property without realizing it.  So, with $H = \{id, (12)\} < S_3$, this is what I have:  $(13)H = \{(13), (123)\}, (23)H = \{(23), (132)\}$.  Take one element from each coset and multiply them, say $(123)(132) = id$.  However, $(13)(23) = (132)$, and the inverse of $(132)$ is not an element of $H$.  I don't know why this is so, but as Mr. Tobias Kildetoft said, the order changed.  This is so strange!