# What is an example of a subgroup $H\le S_3$ that is not normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Give an example(s) of a group $G$ and $H\leq G$ (i.e., $H$ is a subgroup of $G$) where $H$ is not normal in $G$.

What about $S_3$ and $\langle(1\;2)\rangle=\{(1),(1\;2)\}$? [Since $(1\;2\;3)(1\;2)(1\;3\;2)=(2\;3)\not\in\langle(1\;2)\rangle$] Does this work? Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, that works, and is the usual counter-example. Any such example, of course, must come from a non-abelian group, so non-abelian groups of small order are the best places to look (you can, for example, find non-normal subgroups of $D_4$ as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not rare to see examples of subgroups of a given group, which are not normal subgroups. I'll give you one from finite groups.

Consider [this finite group of order $8$](http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/htmlfiles8/8_5_2_0.html), call it $G$. Then $2\in G$ and $H=\{0,1\}$ is a subgroup of $G$. But $H$ is not normal, since
$$2H=\{2,4\}\ne\{2,3\}=H2.$$